# Knockout paging

Tags: knockout.js, paging

I have a viewmodel with paging functions which maintain pageIndex property. Viewmodel has a pages array with pages. Each page has its own pageNumber property.

paging code of my viewmodel:

```
//paging
pageIndex: ko.observable(),
pageSize: ko.observable(),
pageCount: ko.observable(),
pages: ko.observableArray([]),
nextPage: function () {
    alert("Next");
    this.pageIndex = this.pageIndex + 1;
    alert(this.pageIndex);
},
previousPage: function () {
    //alert("PRev");
    this.pageIndex = this.pageIndex - 1;
    alert(this.pageIndex);
},
gotoPage: function (page) {
    //alert("GO:" + page.pageNumber);
    this.pageIndex = page.pageNumber;
    alert(this.pageIndex);
},
```

In my view, I have a nested list as:

```
<nav id="paging">
<ul class="paginationList">
    <li class="paginationList" data-bind="visible: pageIndex > 0">
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: previousPage"><<</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="paginationList" data-bind="foreach: pages">
    <li class="paginationList">
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.gotoPage, css: { disabled: $parent.pageIndex == $data.pageNumber }, text: $data.pageNumber"></a>     
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="paginationList">
    <li class="paginationList" data-bind="visible: pageIndex < pageCount">
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: nextPage">>></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Its works, but when click "Next" function pageIndex changes but the anchors disabled state doesn't change.

I cant resolve why it happens.

Answer (score 6):

`pageIndex` isn't a property but a function. Set it as:

```
this.pageIndex(page.pageNumber);
```

Comment: Also: "css: { disabled: $parent.pageIndex == $data.pageNumber }" should be changed to: "css: { disabled: $parent.pageIndex() == $data.pageNumber() }"

Comment: Thanks, i`ve tried as is calling as function, but get an error function not defined.

Comment: @Pluto show your code. It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rNU4d/ ( only commented out a line which is related to $parent).

Comment: Thanks @meze; I`ve modified my code as http://jsfiddle.net/rNU4d/5/ but pages number does not show. I'm new with knockout.

Comment: @Pluto all is correct except that you haven't filled `pages` array and `$data.pageNumber` refers to nothing. It needs to be something like http://jsfiddle.net/rNU4d/7/

Comment: @Pluto So there are two things you need to keep an eye on: contexts and the fact that `ko.observable*` returns a function which you use to read and write value.